# Primary Keys with Duplicated data?

Tags: oracle, database-design, key

I am trying to assign a primary key but some of the data is duplicated? How can we keep the data but still have a primary key?

Comment: Fix your data. What's the point of storing the same information more than once?

Comment: By the definition, data in primary key column must be unique

Answer (score 3):

The only time I ran into this in 17 years of database work, was due to an error in the data.  A single customer had been entered twice, with the same id, into a table that had no primary key.

When it was desired to declare a primary key, it was necessary to clear up the data error first, in order to be able to use the most logical column as a primary key.

So my advice is to see whether all the data in your table conforms to the business rules as well as checking to see if the business rules imply using this column as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is a series of *unique values*.  So you can keep your duplicate data or you can have a primary key, but not both.

Alternatively you can use a surrogate key, by adding an ID column to the table and populating it from a sequence.  Of course, in this situation the "primaruy key" is meaningless because you're not enforcing the uniqueness of the business key.  But at least you can fool yourself that you have realtional integrity.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can guess, you have data, and you're trying to assign a column as the primary key, however the data has duplicate values for that column.

Primary keys need to be unique. That's databases 101. If the only thing that works as a primary key is a duplicate, you're not structuring your tables properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create a non-unique index on the columns to be constrained, then add a primary key constraint with the `novalidate` clause, eg:

```
create table t1 (x number);

insert into t1 (x) values (1);
insert into t1 (x) values (1);
commit;

create index t1_pk on t1 (x);

alter table t1 add (
   constraint t1_pk primary key (x) novalidate
);
```

I must stress however that, although possible, this is usually bad design!

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are unique, so if you want to have duplicate data in a certain column, that same column can't be the primary kay of that table.